# Convert ISO String Date to %d-%m-%Y %H%M%S in C

Tags: c, date, byte, ascii

I have a ASCII array (converted String date format 2023-26-04T12:01:42.123+01:00)
The byte array is now:

```
 2023-04-26T12:01:42.123+01:00
 32 30 32 33 2D 30 34 2D 32 36 54 30 39 3A 31 31 3A 35 37 2E 39 36 37 2B 30 39 3A 31 31
```

The format of final date must be in

```
 DD-MM-YYYY HHmmss (parse ascii bytes and trim).
```

Is there any function in C which can help in conversion.
So far I have done, but seems incorrect:

```
void convertUTCTimeto24HourFormat(const void* data)
{
    char buf[sizeof "24-04-2023 245957"]; //sample to know size
    struct tm tm;
    /* 1. Convert buffer to time struct */
    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    /* 2. strip the time and zone from data */    
    (void)strptime(data, "%FT%TZ", &tm);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d-%m-%Y %H%M%S", &tm);  
}
```

Is struct tm not the way? Or creating char array and parsing one by one (conversion from ascii to hex and back seems tedious)

Comment: Is the input really `2023-26-04` or is it `2023-04-26`. That would be the first time that I see YYYYDDMM as format. Usually when the year comes first, it is always the month in the middle and days last. The byte stream below the text is that way ( 30 34 == 04 and 32 36 == 26)

Comment: Using `strptime` and `struct tm` is certainly one way, if you have `strptime`.  But I'd use an explicit format like `%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S`.  (I don't know what `%FT%TZ` is supposed to mean.)  If you can't get `strptime` to work, you can always use `sscanf` into the individual members of `struct tm`, being careful to adjust `tm_year` and `tm_mon` per their annoying offsets.

Comment: What is the meaning of that byte array on top? The content is not the same as the string above.

Comment: If you don't need to convert time itself but only it's representation from some *string* to another *string*, parse input as string (e.g. with `sscanf()` or regex) and generate new one, e.g. with `snprintf()`. Need no time-specific functions.

Comment: Re “seems incorrect”: Why does it seem incorrect? Do you have an example where it fails? If so, provide a [mre].

Comment: @Gerhardh `32 30 32 …` taken as hex is `2023-04-26T09:11:57.967+09:11`.  So it's pretty close to the string above. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit I know. And the string was already edited to match better, but "pretty close" is still off. If that is just supposed to be the same content as hex values, then it is not really needed. If it is something else, then we need to know how to convert the values into the string shown.

Comment: @Gerhardh I don't think we have to worry about that.  Many beginning programmers have nearly insurmountable difficulties distinguishing between text and binary data.  So even though it was unnecessary and mildly inaccurate, I appreciated the OP's effort to explain the format of the incoming `const void* data`.  It was clearly supposed to be the same content as hex values; there was no chance it was something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any function in C which can help in conversion(?)

Yes, `strptime()/strftime()` are useful, when available. See below.

> Is struct tm not the way?

`struct tm` is *one* way to do this.

---

Problems with  `(void)strptime(data, "%FT%TZ", &tm);`

- `strptime()` is not a standard C library function.  Various systems define it like [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime).
- `"%FT%TZ"` likely should be `"%FT%T%z"`: Add `%` , `z` for offset, not `Z` name.
- Ignoring the return value.  Good code checks the return value for errors.

OP's *ASCII array* lacks a null character, needed for `strptime()`.

---

Untested alternative:

```
// Return error flag
int convertUTCTimeto24HourFormat(size_t buf_size, char *buf, const void* data) {
    // Copy data and append a \0
    char source[sizeof "2023-04-26T12:01:42.123+01:00"];
    strncpy(source, data, sizeof source - 1);
    source[sizeof source - 1] = '\0';
    
    //  Parse string
    char buf[sizeof "24-04-2023 245957"];
    struct tm tm = { 0 };// Use this instead of memset().
    if (strptime(source, "%FT%T%z", &tm) == NULL) {
      return 1;
    }

    // Form new string.
    if (strftime(buf, buf_size, "%d-%m-%Y %H%M%S", &tm) == 0) {
      return 2;
    }
    puts(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Ref: [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Assume OP's typo:

```
(converted String date format 2023-26-04T12:01:42.123+01:00) Original
(converted String date format 2023-04-26T12:01:42.123+01:00) Change in month/day
```

OP's sample byte array is questionable

```
04-26T12:01:42.123+01:00
32 30 32 33 2D 30 34 2D 32 36 54 30 39 3A 31 31 3A 35 37 2E 39 36 37 2B 30 39 3A 31 31
```

I suspect it is instead

```
 2  0  2  3  -  0  4  -  2  6  T  0  9  :  1  1  :  5  7  .  9  6  7  +  0  9  :  1  1
32 30 32 33 2D 30 34 2D 32 36 54 30 39 3A 31 31 3A 35 37 2E 39 36 37 2B 30 39 3A 31 31
```